# How to logout CSH session?

Tags: csh

I connected to CentOS server via SSH. In SSH terminal I executed

```
csh
```

command mistakenly. Now when I use

```
logout
```

command it throws

```
Not a login shell.
```

output. How can I logout CSH and return back to SSH?

Comment: `exit`? Ctrl+D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit` or sending End-Of-File (`^D`) should terminate the shell.